# Wordpress prdoes not show

Tags: wordpress

I have had wordpress problems all day. The issue now is I installed a fresh wordpress with most recent release and now nothing shows you can view at [can see anything link to website](https://www.dogoodperks.com/2019)

Comment: Are you able to access `wp-admin` ? Is it the same error ?

Answer (score 0):

When accessing the original `http://www.dogoodperks.com` i am getting an error **Error establishing a database connection**.

This can be due to multiple reasons. You have to check the following

- Check the username and password of database given when setting up wordpress is the same. Any changes can cause error
- Check if the wordpress files or database is corrupted